# Making the search field (with results) disappear when clicking outside on Ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile-safari

I have two html elements as follows :

1. A input element whose class is "fts-input". This input serves as a search box.
2. A div container, containing all the list of results, whose class is "dropdown-items-wrapper"

I made a code who worked in all browsers except Safari, that made the search results disappear when clicking outside of the search field, or outside of the search results. This code is :

```
    var ftsInput = $('.fts-input');
    var dropDownList = $('.dropdown-items-wrapper');

 function closeSearchWhenClickingElsewhere(event, dropDown) {
    var clickedElement = event.target;
    if (!clickedElement) return;

    var elementClasses = clickedElement.classList;
    var clickedOnSearchOrResults = elementClasses.contains('fts-input') ||
        elementClasses.contains('dropdown-items-wrapper');

    if(!clickedOnSearchOrResults) {
        dropDown.fadeOut('slow');
    }
}

    $document.on('click', (e) => {
        this.closeSearchWhenClickingElsewhere(e, dropDownList);
    });
```

But this code seems to not work on Ipad (iOs Safari). Do you have a clue why it isn't working ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap around `document` within the `$` jQuery symbol.

So your code becomes,

```
$(document).on('click', (e) => {
    this.closeSearchWhenClickingElsewhere(e, dropDownList);
});
```

Alternatively, you can assign as this:

```
$document = $(document);
```

Created a fiddle for you which works fine on Safari 10: https://jsfiddle.net/1ymrtcbf/

Comment: I'm using Angular, and $document is native service of Angular represting the document element

Comment: Can you try the above change and let me know if it worked?

Comment: Of course. I'm trying it now (It takes time to delete cache etc.. )